# Extending type signature of System while using `boost::numeric::odeint`

Tags: c++, boost, odeint

The system of ode $f'(x,t) = f(x,t)$ has to have the following signature as mentioned [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/numeric/odeint/doc/html/boost_numeric_odeint/odeint_in_detail/steppers.html)

```
void sys( const state_type & /*x*/ , state_type & /*dxdt*/ , const double /*t*/ )
{
    // ...
}
```

It is possible to modify it to the following

```
void sys( const state_type & /*x*/ , state_type & /*dxdt*/ , const double /*t*/, void * params )
{
    // do something with params now ...
}
```

Comment: How will you set the params? What about `boost::bind` ? They have some examples in the page you refer to. You would do something like `boost::bind( &fn , _1 , _2 , _3, &params)` to bind the params, and give it the required signature.

Comment: @DanMašek `params` are set the way you did in your answer. I am trying it out. I'll update here once I get it working.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is to use lambdas. In C++14 you write them as

```
auto func = [&params]( auto const& x , auto& dxdt , double t ) {
    sys( x , dxdt , t , &params ); };
rk.do_step(my_fun, inout, t, dt);
```

Furthermore, if you do not need to call third party libraries and pass `params` via `void*` consider to use a functor to access your parameters:

```
 struct sys
 {
     param_t param;
     void operator()( state_type const& x , state_type& dxdt , double t ) const
     {
         // implement sys and access params
     }
 };

 sys s;
 rk.do_step(s, inout, t, dt);
```

This is exactly why odeint uses function object. You can use everything which looks like a function. And a class with some member and appropriate `operator()` behaves exactly like function.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`boost::bind`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/bind/doc/html/bind.html) or (perhaps `std::bind`) to bind the 4<sup>th</sup> parameter to a pointer the params object that you want to use. This will create a function object with the correct signature.

Then you should be able to use it as usual.

```
params_t params;
// Set the parameters...

auto my_fun = boost::bind(&sys, _1, _2, _3, &params);
// ...
rk.do_step(my_fun, inout, t, dt);
```

Comment: Surprising `boost::bind` failed with error ` binding value of type 'const vector<[2 * ...]>' to reference to type 'vector<[2 * ...]>' drops 'const' qualifier` but everything worked with `std::bind` .